# Publishing site, CSWP and Search

Tags: search, content-search-web-part

We are using the Content Search WebPart on a page in a publishing site to show items that are in another site collection. If a person searches the site the CSWP is on they do not get any results that are part of the CSWP. It seems counter intuitive that you have to go to the other site collection to search.  Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: what sharepoint version are you using?

Comment: What are the query settings being used by the CSWP? @Supermode CSWP is part of 2013

Answer (score 0):

In the search settings section for the site collection you need to select "Enable custom scopes (such as "All Sites") by connecting this site collection with the following Search". Then use only contextual scopes (such as "This Site").

Original post
"http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1f56ac3e-fa1a-4f1b-9444-811a84584f50/search-across-multiple-site-collections"

SP 2013:
Chris O'Brien has posted article about this:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html